# GTK applications aren't themed on Plasma Desktop

Tags: themes, kde, plasma

I have installed `plasma-desktop` on my girlfriend's Ubuntu 12.04 box, so now she can log on to a KDE desktop, which she likes.

However, GTK applications are not themed.

Here's a screenshot she took of the problem, left is how GTK apps look, right is how it'd be desired:

[image: not themed vs themed]

*What can fix it?*

**What I've tried:**

I tried installing `kcm-gtk`, and installed a host of other packages (`qtcurve` `qtcurve-i18n` `kwin-style-qtcurve` `kde-style-qtcurve` `gtk2-engines-qtcurve` `gtk2-engines-oxygen` `gtk3-engines-oxygen` `oxygen-molecule`), so now I have a "GTK+ Appearance" item in Application Appearance under System Settings, but as much as I change its theme to Oxygen Molecule or QtCurve, it does nothing (apps look just the same).

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `kcmshell5 kcm_style`, navigate to “GNOME/GTK Application Style”, and apply the best available entry of what the “GTK theme” dropdown provides.